# Adding dataframe to original dataframe Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I need to add my dataframe "sentiments_df" to my older dataframe "example_reviews" using pd.concat in Python Pandas. I have attached a picture below of what the dataframes look like.

[Dataframes Picture from Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJuBO.png)

I've tried the following code, but I get a syntax error. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Code

```
df = pd.concat = ([example_reviews,sentiments_df],axis=1)
```

Error

```
  Input In [447]
    df = pd.concat = ([example_reviews,sentiments_df],axis=1)
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using and the error you are getting.

Comment: Simply `df = pd.concat([example_reviews,sentiments_df],axis=1)`, probably.

Comment: I've tried that too but get following error
'''
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [449], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 # Answer - concat example_reviews and sentiments_df
----> 3 df = pd.concat([example_reviews,sentiments_df],axis=1)
      4 df

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

```

Comment: It seems likely you've overwritten `pd.concat` with a list in one of the runs of `pd.concat=...`. You can check this with `type(pd.concat)`

Comment: @G.Anderson will be correct. Refresh your jupyter kernel, rerun your code without the line that overwrites `pd.concat` with a list, and then add the line I recommended above. Should work.

Comment: @G.Anderson you are exactly right! It comes back as "list". Is there a particular way to fix this issue? please let me know. thanks.

Comment: `del pd.concat` and `import pandas as pd` should set you to rights

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `pd.concat([example_reviews, sentiments_df], axis=1)`.
The `=` after `pd.concat` should be removed.

Comment: I've tried that too but get following error

 ''' TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) Input In [449], in <cell line: 3>() 1 # Answer - concat example_reviews and sentiments_df ----> 3 df = pd.concat([example_reviews,sentiments_df],axis=1) 4 df 

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable 

```

Comment: Can you restart your kernel or close and reopen your jupyter notebook and try again. Maybe you've overwritten `pd.concat` by running `pd.concat = ([example_reviews,sentiments_df],axis=1)` like @G. Anderson commented.